# Attribute Error: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'best_params_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am getting this Error while doing **Grid-Search** for my **Classification** with **Random Forest**.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf2 = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 50)
rf2.fit(X_train1, y_train1)

### Grid Search ###
num_leafs = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

parameters3 = [{'n_estimators' : range(100,800,20),
             'max_depth': range(1,20,2),
             'min_samples_leaf':num_leafs
             }]


gs3 = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf2,
                  param_grid=parameters3,
                  cv = 10,
                  n_jobs = -1)

gs3 = rf2.fit(X_train1, y_train1)

gs3.best_params_ # <- thats where I get the Error
```

I don't know the Problem because it worked the same way (different parameters of course) with a SVM and a Decision Tree.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:
`gs3 = rf2.fit(X_train1, y_train1)`

by this:
`gs3.fit(X_train1, y_train1)`

Then you'll be able to use: 
`gs3.best_params_`

You error was caused by the fact that you reassigned `gs3` to the `RandomForest()` call, so `gs3` wasn't a `GridSearchCV` object anymore.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Well, you do not fit the `GridSearch` object but instead, you fit the `model` (rf2) and then assign it to the `gs3` parameter.**

You have:

```
gs3 = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf2,
                  param_grid=parameters3,
                  cv = 10,
                  n_jobs = -1)
gs3 = rf2.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
gs3.best_params_ # <- thats where I get the Error
```

**You need:**

```
gs3 = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf2,
                  param_grid=parameters3,
                  cv = 10,
                  n_jobs = -1)
gs3.fit(X_train1, y_train1) # fit the GridSearchCV object
gs3.best_params_ # <- thats where I get the Error
```